# How do I reference a game object in a prefabs folder? Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to reference a game object in a prefabs folder to insatiate how would I do that. also, the object I'm trying to reference is a particle effect if that helps anyone who is answering this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MonoBehaviour` scipt, add a `[SerializeField] GameObject _prefab` field.

e.g. here I've made a script called `SlabMaker` that makes endless terrain utilising a prefab:

```
public class SlabMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]                 
    private GameObject _prefab;
.
.
.
```

Then in the **Editor**, select the object with the previously mentioned script attached.  In my example I have attached the `SlabMaker` script to a GameObject with the highly original name of *"_Game"*.  Notice the properties for the `SlabMaker` appearing in the **Inspector** along with a field for **Prefab**.  Hurrah!:

[image]

...then drag whatever prefab you wish to use from the **Project** window into the **Prefab** property in the **Properties** pane:

In this example I will use my fancy jumpjet plane.  Why I want to make endless terrain with Harrier Jumpjets is anyones' guess:

[image]

Now then all you have to do is to instantiate the prefab in your script. Job done.

Comment: uhmmmm can you dumb that down I'm kinda new to unity and coding in general

Comment: @Killercarrot102 there you go good sir.